# Is it possible to read a private key from a PEM file without looping through every possible algorithm or writing an ASN.1 parser?

Tags: java, private-key, pki

I'm looking at reading one or more private keys from PEM-encoded DER files and I'm wondering if it can be done robustly without just trying all possible algorithms (which is ugly and brute-forcey) or writing an ASN.1 parser?

I'm trying to do this without any dependencies other than the standard Java library. I'm sure BouncyCastle can do this, but I'm interested in what is possible with out-of-the-box Java.

A PEM-encoded DER file is the somewhat familiar file that looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
[base64-encoded DER data]
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

In the example above, the text indicates the type of key: it's an elliptic-curve key, so we can ask Java for an EC key factory:

```
byte[] keyBytes = // get DER bytes
KeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
PrivateKey key = kf.generateKey(spec);
```

But it's also possible that the file does not advertise its contents, like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
[base64 encoded DER data]
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

In this case, I see only two obvious possibilities given the API:

1. Loop through all supported algorithms, trying them all and ignoring certain errors
2. Implement an ASN.1 parser to determine the actual type of the key, then use the right `KeyFactory`

Looping seems straightforward, but IMO distasteful:

```
byte[] keyBytes = // get DER bytes
KeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
PrivateKey key = null;
for(String algorithm : new String[] { "EC", "RSA", "DSA" }) {
  try {
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
    key = kf.generatePrivateKey(keyBytes);
  } catch (....) {
    // Ignore "wrong algorithm" exceptions
  }
}
// "key" is either null (couldn't read/interpret) or non-null and OK
```

This is also potentially time-consuming, though typically key setup is a "rare" operation, so performance isn't strictly important.

The only other option I can think of is inspecting the data to find out exactly what the data represent, and then use the correct type:

```
byte[] keyBytes = // get DER bytes
KeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
ASN1Parser a1p = new ASN1Parser();
String algorithm  = a1p.parse(keyBytes).getAlgorithm();
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
PrivateKey key = fk.generatePrivateKey(spec);
```

Contrast this with reading an X.509 Certificate, where you don't have to know anything about the algorithm to load the certificate:

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
cf.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(certBytes));
```

Am I missing something in the API that would allow this kind of "just do it for me" mechanics, or is it strictly necessary to know the algorithm before loading the key material?

Writing an ASN.1 parser isn't trivial and though they exist in third-party libraries, I'd like to limit the dependencies as much as possible.

Comment: Your first example `BEGIN/END EC PRIVATE KEY` is **NOT** a PKCS8 key and can't be read by _any_ JCA `KeyFactory`. For the PKCS8-clear format `BEGIN/END PRIVATE KEY` your ASN1Parser approach is almost workable; you need `.getAlgorithmIdentifier() .getAlgorithm[AsString]()`. `CertificateFactory` (or rather the 'engine' behind it) actually does the equivalent for X.509 SPKI instead of PKCS8. Remember both PKCS8 and 'traditional' privatekey PEM files can be encrypted, using very different methods, adding to the complexity.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I didn't want to make the question even more complicated by introducing encryption of the private key. I didn't realize that "BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY" wasn't PKCS8 but instead a separate standard (RFC5915).